# react-boostrap with react-hook-from with zod

Tags: typescript, react-bootstrap, react-hook-form, zod

I am having trouble implementing the errors with the inbuilt react-bootstrap Form.Control.Feedback

```
<div className="mb-3">
    <InputGroup className="mb-3">
        <Form.Control
            {...register("email")}
            id="email"
            type="email"
            placeholder="Email"
            isValid={!errors.email}
            isInvalid={!!errors.email}
        />
    </InputGroup>
    {errors.email && <p className="error">{errors.email.message}</p>}
</div>
```

This obviously works but I wanted to have the errors inside the:

```
<div className="mb-3">
    <InputGroup className="mb-3">
        <Form.Control
            id="password"
            name="password"
            type="password"
            placeholder="Password"
            onChange={handleChange}
            value={values.password}
            isValid={touched.password && !errors.password}
            isInvalid={touched.password && !!errors.password}
        />
        {touched.password && errors.password ? (
            <Form.Control.Feedback type="invalid">
                {errors.password}
            </Form.Control.Feedback>
         ) : (
            <InputGroup.Text>
                <i className="fas fa-lock" />
            </InputGroup.Text>
         )}
    </InputGroup>
</div>
```

This code is using formik and yup
but I wanted to move to react-hook-form and zod.

Can someone help me on this?

Errors are not showing if I try to use Form.Control.Feedback with react-hook-form and zod.

Also if there is anything you might think will work better let me know.